# How to translate a list comprehension to a version using concatMap?

Tags: haskell

How can I translate a list comprehension to a version that uses `concatMap` instead?

```
dPairs xs ys = [(x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys, x /= y]
```

Comment: Hint: `concatMap (\x -> _someList) xs` will give you the result of ‘do something with each element of `x` to get a list, and then concatenate the lists’. Same with `concatMap (\y -> _someList) ys`. Now think about how you can combine those.

Comment: @bradrn can you give me another hint?

Comment: Try experimenting in `ghci`. For example, **Input:** `concatMap (\x -> [0, 1, 2, 3]) ["this", "is", "sparta"]`. **Output:** `[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]`

Comment: If you want a stronger hint, `concatMap (\x -> [all possible pairs (x, y) for the given fixed value of x]) xs`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq do you mean  ```concatMap (\x -> [zip [x] ys]) xs```

Comment: You have the right idea, but `zip [x] ys` will only create at most one pair, `(x, head ys)`. Try using a list comprehension instead.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq my idea is first create a list with possible pairs with ```concatMap (\x -> ??? ys]) (\y -> ??? xs])```, then I'll sort and turn them into tuples, but I dont know which function should I use for ???

Comment: As I mentioned, a list comprehension is a good start: `\x -> [(x, y) | y <- ys, x /= y]`. If you don't like list comprehensions, you can try `\x -> zip (repeat x) ys` to create the list of pairs, then filter them out with something like `filter (x /=)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension can be rewritten to `do` syntax, like:

```
import Control.Monad(guard)

dPairs xs ys = do
    x <- xs
    y <- ys
    guard (x /= y)
    return (x,y)
```

This `do` expression is just syntactical sugar. Indeed, the [*do expression* section in the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) shows how do desugar these:

```
dPairs xs ys = xs >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> guard (x /= y) >> return (x,y)))
```

For the `instance Monad []`, the `return` and bind function `>>=` are defined as:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    xs >>= f = concatMap f xs
```

hence that means that our `dPairs` is defined as:

```
dPairs xs ys = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> guard (x /= y) >> [(x,y)]) ys) xs
```

The [**`guard :: Alternative f => Bool -> f ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) is defined as:

> ```
> guard True = return ()
> guard False = empty
> ```

so for a list, it is defined as:

```
-- guard for list
guard True = [()]
guard False = []
```

A strict translation is thus:

```
dPairs xs ys = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> (concatMap (\_ -> [(x,y)]) (if x /= y then [()] else [])) ys) xs
```

This however is a quite overcomplicated expression. For example a `concatMap` where the function each time maps to a singleton list, is just a `map` without wrapping elements in a singleton list. We thus can simplify this to:

```
dPairs xs ys = concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> map (const (x,y)) (if x /= y then [()] else [])) ys) xs
```

The `guard` furthere is just a filtering mechanism, so we can filter with:

```
dPairs xs ys = concatMap (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y)) (filter (x /=) ys)) xs
```

A more simple function is however:

```
dPairs :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
dPairs xs ys = filter (uncurry (/=)) ((,) <$> xs <*> ys)
```

As [@chepner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614612/how-to-translate-a-list-comprehension-to-a-version-using-concatmap/60616839?noredirect=1#comment107242929_60616839), the Haskell report also has a [section how to transform "desugar" list comprehension to `concatMap`s](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11).

Comment: Also worth noting: the Haskell Report shows how to translate a [list comprehension](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) to `concatMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Since list comprehensions are syntax sugar for the list monad, and the `>>=` operator for lists *is* `concatMap` (flipped), you could translate the list comprehension into a `do` block, then into an expression that uses `>>=`, and finally substitute it with `concatMap` by flipping its arguments. E.g.:

```hs
  [ (x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys, x /= y ]

≡ do x <- xs
     y <- ys
     if (x /= y) then [(x, y)] else []

≡ xs >>= \x ->
  ys >>= \y ->
  if (x /= y) then [(x, y)] else []

≡ (>>=) xs (\x ->
  (>>=) ys (\y ->
  if (x /= y) then [(x, y)] else []))

≡ (>>=) xs (\x -> (>>=) ys (\y -> if (x /= y) then [(x, y)] else []))

≡ concatMap (\x -> (>>=) ys (\y -> if (x /= y) then [(x, y)] else [])) xs

≡ concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> if (x /= y) then [(x, y)] else []) ys) xs
```

(One could also have gone through [`guard`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard).)

Comment: It's not *necessarily* syntactic sugar, but the Haskell Report does provide a set of identities that list comprehensions have to obey, regardless of how they are implemented.